# How can I obtain the model's name or the content type of a Django object?

Tags: python, django, django-models, content-type

Let's say I am in the save code. How can I obtain the model's name or the content type of the object, and use it?

```
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self):
        I am here....I want to obtain the model_name or the content type of the object
```

This code works, but I have to know the model_name:

```
import django.db.models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model=model_name)
model = content_type.model_class()
```

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You can get the model name from the object like this:

```
self.__class__.__name__
```

If you prefer the content type, you should be able to get that like this:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self)
```

Comment: If you have a database browser tool you can see that a django_content_type is created. It contains some fields, like name, app_label and model. I need to obtain that model information from the class I am in.

Comment: The model field is a lowercase string and it is derived from the class name.

Comment: Then do something like 'ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self)', followed by 'return ct.app_label' or whichever ContentType attribute you need.

Comment: Or just lowercase the class name to get the content type, whichever you prefer...'print self.__class__.__name__.lower()'

Comment: Thank you. ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self) did the trick

Comment: The solution via `ContentType` requires an additional SQL request.

Answer (score 11):

The method `get_for_model` does some fancy stuff, but there are some cases when it's better to not use that fancy stuff. In particular, say you wanted to filter a model that linked to ContentType, maybe via a generic foreign key?? The question here was what to use for `model_name` in:

> content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model=model_name)

Use `Foo._meta.model_name`, or if you have a `Foo` object, then `obj._meta.model_name` is what you're looking for. Then, you can do things like

```
Bar.objects.filter(content_type__model=Foo._meta.model_name)
```

This is an efficient way to filter the `Bar` table to return you objects which link to the `Foo` content type via a field named `content_type`.

Answer (score 5):

Using gravelpot's answer, to give a direct answer to the OP's question:

We can get the object's class through `instance.__class__` and then pass it to the  `get_for_model` function:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance.__class__)
```