# Django: how to get an arbitrary model from a POST request

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a Comment Model that uses `ContentType` and `GenericForeignKey` so that a comment can be attached to an instance of an arbitrary model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    ...
    text = models.TextField() 
    target_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='comment_target',
        null=True, blank=True)
    target_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    target_object = GenericForeignKey("target_content_type", "target_object_id")
```

And I have a form for creating Comments:

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    new_comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':2}))
```

The form is used like this:

```
  <form method="POST" action="{% url 'comments:create' %}">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form | crispy }}
    <input type='hidden' name = 'target_id' value='{{q.id}}' />
    <input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value='Add reply' />
  </form>
```

In my Create view, how can I get the model of the originating object, or the `ContentType` & id, so that I can create a new Comment?

```
def comment_create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
      if form.is_valid():
        text = form.cleaned_data.get('new_comment')  
        target_object_id = request.POST.get('target_id')
        target_content_type = ?
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

When you generate the form, add a hidden field that also includes the content type id.

From there you can then query the in-built Django `ContentType` model, like so:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
my_model = ContentType.objects.get(id=some_id).model_class()
```

---

As for how to get the content type id in there, because you can't use methods that take arguments you can either change how your form is constructed (adding a hidden field and populating a default (better way) or creating a template tag that would act as a helper function to populate a hidden field in the html template (easier way).

In either case, you can then just use the `ContentType` again to call this:

```
ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(my_item)
```

[Credit to this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863332/how-can-i-obtain-the-models-name-or-the-content-type-of-a-django-object)

Comment: Thanks!

How to I get the content type id in my form?

Comment: @43Tesseracts I've added some details on how to do that.